# How do I sort words by syllable count?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

How do I perform an ascending sort of a word list, based upon how many syllables each word contains?

Example Input:

```
something
important
dog
cat
bookshelf
```

Example Output:

```
dog
cat
something
bookshelf
important
```

Comment: Sorting is easy; do you have something that counts syllables?

Comment: `perl` has a module called `Lingua::EN::Syllable` which "estimates the number of syllables in the word passed to it."  http://search.cpan.org/~neilb/Lingua-EN-Syllable-0.30/ (packaged for debian as `liblingua-en-syllable-perl`)

Comment: @JeffSchaller I didn't have anything to count the syllables. I think the issue was that I was searching for the counting and sorting at the same time.

Comment: @cas Thank you very much, your solution appears to work wonderfully.

Comment: also FYI, I just spotted this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405161/detecting-syllables-in-a-word

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This perl script builds a hash with words (read one per line from stdin, and/or from any filenames listed on the command line) as keys, and syllable counts as the values.

Then it prints the hash keys, sorted by the syllable counts.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl

use strict;

use Lingua::EN::Syllable;

my %words = ();

while(<>) {
   chomp;
   $words{$_} = syllable($_);
};

print join("\n",sort { $words{$a} <=> $words{$b} } keys(%words)), "\n";
```

Output:

```
cat
dog
bookshelf
something
important
```

If you want to print the syllable count along with each word, change the last line to something like this:

```perl
foreach my $word (sort { $words{$a} <=> $words{$b} } keys(%words)) {
    printf "%2i: %s\n", $words{$word}, $word;
};
```

Output:

```
 1: cat
 1: dog
 2: bookshelf
 3: something
 3: important
```

This version highlights the fact that, as the module itself claims, it only **estimates** the syllable count.  "bookshelf" is correctly counted as having only two syllables but "something" should also be two.

I haven't examined the module code closely, but it's probably getting confused by the `e` after the `m`.  In many (most?) words, that wouldn't be a silent `e` and would count as an extra syllable.

Comment: you can accept this answer and mark it as "answered" by clicking on the big tick mark if it answered your question.

Comment: I have a tremendous amount of words to analyse and really, I'm looking to trim the most burdensome words to say from the list, so +/-1 syllable is just fine.

Comment: BTW, this script highlights one of the benefits of learning `perl` - there are CPAN modules to do pretty nearly anything you can think of, so many programs that would be very complicated to write in other languages are as trivial as this to write in `perl` - because much of the work has already been done by the module authors....all you have to do is use the tool(s) they provide.  Often, the hardest part is finding the module that does what you need - in this case, it took about 30 seconds to do a google search for `perl count syllables`

Comment: FYI, a CPAN search says there are 993 modules matching `Lingua::`,  some of them may be of use to you: http://search.cpan.org/search?m=module&q=Lingua%3A%3A&s=1&n=100